# Awesome WM cannot be used with mouse after a while

Tags: fedora, awesome

I use plain Awesome WM on Fedora 22. After a while (perhaps connected to suspend/wakeup) I can still use mouse for the applications but Awesome WM does not react on mouse clicks any more. Restarting Awesome WM does not help either. This has not happened on Ubuntu so far.

Is there something I could do?

Comment: Have you accidentally turned on Caps Lock, Num Lock or Scroll Lock? Some programs don't recognize their keybindings when a lock is on.

Comment: I have mapped calls lock to control, therefore it could get activated before it is remapped. But I should see the caps lock in other programs, right? Scroll lock is not active, at least the LED is off.

Comment: Oh, an it's not the key bindings, it's the mouse bindings only.